# AES Decrypt full row in MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, encryption, aes

The code block that i use is below:

```
SELECT * FROM crypted_tbl WHERE Username=AES_ENCRYPT('aydu', 'usa2010');
```

When i use this command, i get

```
”`‡œ™uûx“¢Í®i
‘¨åµüÐzêlæZ1­ØÝ
GN“bˆg(ž÷’8
```

(Username, Password, AuthorizationType)

How can i decrypt full row by using a MySQL command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid you're going to have to decrypt each column explicitly rather than trying to decrypt *. If you're going only with MySQL you'll have to do:

```
SELECT AES_DECRYPT(column1, 'seed'), AES_DECRYPT(column2, 'seed'), etc.
WHERE Username=AES_ENCRYPT('aydu', 'usa2010');
```

If you want to build your statement in c# or another platform then you can query the table structure and build the SELECT statement dynamically so that you don't necessarily have to hard code each column name into the SELECT. Just be aware of the performance hit by querying the table structure before each query.

```
SELECT * FROM `information_schema`.`tables`
WHERE table_name = 'crypted_tbl';
```